# what's the meaning of "*" in the "*ngFor"?

Tags: angular

I'm learning Angular 2 recently. And I can't understand the meaning of "*" in *ngFor. Could anyone explain it for me?

Thank you!

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#what-are-structural-directives

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When we reviewed the NgFor and NgIf built-in directives, we called out
> an oddity of the syntax: the asterisk (*) that appears before the
> directive name.
>
> The * is a bit of syntactic sugar that makes it easier to read and
> write directives that modify HTML layout with the help of templates.
> NgFor, NgIf, and NgSwitch all add and remove element subtrees that are
> wrapped in  tags.

**Meaning**

`ngFor` can **only** be applied to a `<template>` element.

`*ngFor` can be applied **to any element**. When used the `<template>` element is created behind the scene.